# Sinon.js calledWithExactly() dynamic number of arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, sinon

Let's consider the following function:

```
function MyClass(...);
MyClass.prototype.funcToTest = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    ...
}
```

I wish to be able to test with what arguments this function was called with.
In my test I do the following:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
sinon.spy(obj, 'funcToTest');
var args = [5, 3, 8];
MyClass.prototype.funcToTest.apply(obj, args);
sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(obj.funcToTest, args); // Here's the problem
```

The problem is that this assert fails and I'm not sure why.ith?

Answer (score 0):

*See my second comment to Vsevolod Goloviznin answer.
I found a solution, don't know if it's the best one, but I'm creating a new array to pass to the assert with the `apply` function, like following:

```
var arr = [].slice.call(args, 0);
arr.unshift(obj.funcToTest);
sinon.assert.calledWithExactly.apply(null, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- you are spying on `obj.funcToTest`, but you're *calling* `MyClass.prototype.funcToTest`. For the purpose of this test, those are two different things;
- the assertion is checking if the method got called with a single argument consisting of an array, and not 3 arguments;

Here's something that works:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
sinon.spy(obj, 'funcToTest');
var args = [5, 3, 8];
obj.funcToTest.apply(obj, args);

sinon.assert.calledWithExactly.apply(sinon.assert, [ obj.funcToTest ].concat(args))
```

Or with a hardcoded argument list:

```
sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(obj.funcToTest, 5, 3, 8);
```

Comment: Yea I figured I should use apply, I've posted the answer to this. About spying on obj.funcToTest, and calling MyClass.prototype.funcToTest, I don't see the problem, I've wrote tests so far that stubs the function from the prototype but I call it through the instance, and yet the function is being spied on successfully and when I call it sinon assertions works fine on it

Comment: @Jorayen if you instantiate and _then_ stub the prototype, I don't see how it can work. It'll work the other way around, though: stub the prototype, then instantiate. But that's not what your example code was showing.

Comment: yea I over simplified my example. I stub before instantiate in the test setup , but that wasn't my problem to begin with so I didn't even mention it.